# Why does the golden ratio show up as the solution to these two simultaneous equations?

Tags: systems-of-equations, radicals, golden-ratio

I was given the following simultaneous equations to solve on a homework sheet:

$$
x^2 + y^2 = 3\\x-y=1
$$

And when I did so I got the answers of:

$$ 
(\varphi,-1/\varphi)\\
(1/\varphi,-\varphi)
$$

I checked the answer sheet, and this was the correct answer. I know *how* this is correct, having done the quadratic formula and all to work it out in the first place, but what I don't get is *why*. The first equation, $$x^2 + y^2 = 3$$ plots a circle of radius root 3, yet the point $$(\varphi,-1/\varphi)$$ is also on this circle. By my knowledge of alegebra and pythagoras, this hence implies that

$$ \varphi^2 + -1/\varphi^2 = 3 $$

However, given that the golden ratio is

$$ \frac{\sqrt{5}+1}{2} $$

I fail to see how or where a 3 or a root 3 can come from.

Could someone explain how you get from the golden ratio, a very root-5-y constant, to root 3?

Comment: Hint: use that $\varphi-\dfrac{1}{\varphi}=1\,$.

Comment: (Seems to me that you have a misconception) Why are you expecting a "root 3 can come from"? Are you saying that the only real solutions to $x^2 + y^2 = 3 $ must contain a root 3 in some form? EG The point $( 1, \sqrt{2} )$ also lies on this circle, so in your words, how does it relate to $\sqrt{3} $?

Comment: "I checked the answer sheet, and this was the correct answer." I have long thought it was strange that so many student repose such boundless faith in answer sheets. And teachers tacitly condone and encourage that. Ultimately the goal should be that the student thinks a particular thing is the right answer because the student understands why it must be the right answer.

Comment: As another example, take $x^2+y^2=7$ and $x+y=3$. Then the roots are again of the form $p\pm q \sqrt{5}.$ (The shared fact here is that $2(7)-3^2=5$, just as $2(3)-1^2=5$.) For another, take $x^2+y^2=23$ and $x+y=1$. An infinitude of other examples are possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have that
$$x^2+\frac1{x^2}=3 \iff x^4-3x^2+1=0 \iff x^2=\frac{3\pm\sqrt{5}}{2} $$

and then by [nested square roots](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nested_radical)

$$x_{1,2}=\pm \sqrt{\frac{3+\sqrt{5}}{2}}=\pm \frac{1+\sqrt 5}{2}$$

$$x_{3,4}=\pm \sqrt{\frac{3-\sqrt{5}}{2}}=\pm \frac{-1+\sqrt 5}{2}$$

and indeed

$$x^4-3x^2+1=(x^2+x-1)(x^2-x-1)$$

Comment: That makes a lot of sense. I had arrived at all three of the initial equations you wrote down but I'd arrived at them seperately and hadn't made the connection. Once it's obvious that they're all related, it makes a lot more sense. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

From the Quadratic Formula we know that  $u+v=A$ and $uv=B$ iff $u,v$ are the solutions (in $z$) of $z^2-Az+B=0$.

With $x=u$ and $-y=v,$ we have $u+v=1=A$ and $uv=-xy=\frac {1}{2}((x-y)^2-(x^2+y^2))=-1=B.$

So $x,-y$ are the solutions of $z^2-z-1=0.$